# Angular Material multi ng-menu not working with Jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-material

I have Angular 1.5.4 app and I use Angular material also my app use Jquery 1.8.3. My goal is to create multiple menu like [codepen](http://codepen.io/abhishekpabba/pen/NrRJVW).

```
<md-menu-bar>
      <md-menu>
        <button class="md-button md-raised md-default" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">
          Menu
        </button>
        <md-menu-content>           
          <md-menu-item>
            <md-menu>
              <md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">Link1</md-button>
              <md-menu-content>
                <md-menu-item><md-button>Document</md-button></md-menu-item>
                <md-menu-item><md-button>File</md-button></md-menu-item>
              </md-menu-content>
            </md-menu>
          </md-menu-item>
          <md-menu-item>
            <md-menu>
              <md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">Link2</md-button>
              <md-menu-content>
                <md-menu-item><md-button>Document</md-button></md-menu-item>
                <md-menu-item><md-button>File</md-button></md-menu-item>
              </md-menu-content>
            </md-menu>
          </md-menu-item>            
        </md-menu-content>
      </md-menu>   
    </md-menu-bar>
```

But I get error in browser console:

[image]

Comment: Your markup works okay - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/XjmapR?editors=1010#0. The problem seems to be jQuery related.

Comment: When error thrown ? Could you provide working codepen with error?

Comment: It was problem with jQuery, after upgrade it errors gone